# Pyomo turn off presolve of cplex

Tags: cplex, pyomo

I have the problem that i have a iterable model with mutable variable and when cplex find a Infeasible result using the presolve it does have any result to iter with lastone.

Does someone know have to turn off the cplex's presolve?

I'm using Cplex 12.10. And I havent found the way to sett it in that way. Thanks

Comment: First, if the presolve says that the model is infeasible, then I'm not sure how turning off presolve will help because then the main solve will almost certainly also say the model is infeasible. Second, which API are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
opt = SolverFactory("cplex")
opt.options['preprocessing presolve'] = 0
```

Turns presolve off

Comment: Kindly answer the question. posting only code doesn't help.

Comment: I have other problem maybe you know have to fix it, when i turn off the presolve i get a bad result to iter with my mutable variable, but the problem get in a while where the result doesnt change so, probably i need to sett other think to get a better infesiable solucion. I have tried used feasopt mode but I didnt get a diferent result.